# Little Bash Script: Catch Errors?

Tags: bash, macos

I've written (well, remixed to arrive at) this Bash script

```
# pkill.sh
trap onexit 1 2 3 15 ERR

function onexit() {
    local exit_status=${1:-$?}
    echo Problem killing $kill_this
    exit $exit_status
}

export kill_this=$1
for X in `ps acx | grep -i $1 | awk {'print $1'}`; do
  kill $X;
done
```

it works fine but any errors are shown to the display. I only want the `echo Problem killing...` to show in case of error. How can I "catch" (hide) the error when executing the `kill` statement?

**Disclaimer:** Sorry for the long example, but when I make them shorter I inevitably have to explain "what I'm trying to do."

Comment: Is there a reason why you include signals 1,2,3,15 in your trap command?  (These are HUP,INT,QUIT,TERM).  Also, I'd recommend renaming "onexit" to "onerr", since that seems to be what you're using it for (from the signal ERR in your trap command).

Comment: Hi Ed. All good comments, +1. I copied the code (remixed, if you will), so I won't pretend that I analyzed those parts of it. THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# pkill.sh
trap onexit 1 2 3 15 ERR

function onexit() {
    local exit_status=${1:-$?}
    echo Problem killing $kill_this
    exit $exit_status
}

export kill_this=$1
for X in `ps acx | grep -i $1 | awk {'print $1'}`; do
    kill $X 2>/dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        onexit $?
    fi
done
```

Comment: That worked, though I don't know what the 2> does instead of the semicolon in the original....?

Comment: Sorry, I get it: to redirect only stderr. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect `stderr` and `stdout` to `/dev/null` via something like `pkill.sh > /dev/null 2>&1`. If you only want to suppress the output from the `kill` command, only apply it to that line, e.g., `kill $X > /dev/null 2>&1;`

What this does is take send the standard output (`stdout`) from `kill $X` to `/dev/null` (that's the `> /dev/null`), and additionally send `stderr` (the `2`) into `stdout` (the `1`).

Comment: Thanks Hank. I want the echo, I just don't want the output from the kill statement if it fails.

Comment: Then what if you change the line with the kill to `kill $X > /dev/null 2>&1;` ?

Comment: Hank: To redirect *only* `stderr` the proper way would be `2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks Hank, I'm marking this as plus one, marking Johannes' comment as +1 and marking Creasey's answer as best answer because it worked (though it came later).

Answer (score 0):

For my own notes, here's my new code using Paul Creasey's answer:

```
# pkill.sh: this is dangerous and should not be run as root!
trap onexit 1 2 3 15 ERR

#--- onexit() -----------------------------------------------------
#  @param $1 integer  (optional) Exit status.  If not set, use `$?'
function onexit() {
    local exit_status=${1:-$?}
    echo Problem killing $kill_this
    exit $exit_status
}

export kill_this=$1
for X in `ps acx | grep -i "$1" | awk {'print $1'}`; do
  kill $X 2>/dev/null
done
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Just as a side note,

       for X in `ps acx | grep -i "$1" | awk {'print $1'}`; do

could be better written as

       for X in $(ps acx | awk '/$1/ {print $1}); do

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to modify this script quite soon to incorporate your changes (which got eaten by the comments formatting) and the one on the question itself.